# Pandas dataframe join by splitting the values and get results with concatenation

Tags: python, regex, pandas, join

I'm trying to join two Dataframes and get columns from right table and populate in left table.

if I do join directly it gets data only for items which match but few rows have multiple values in "col1",
so it doesn't match the values.  Is there any better way to lookup for both items in the cell and return the matching items with concatenation?

Below is the Table1.

[image]

Below is the table2

[image]

It should join the items which are marked 'Yes' in "Col3" in table 1 and get the results as below.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please include your data in the post itself, not in images :) Some more explanations of what you’re trying to do might be helpful. Also, I can’t see any column named `Col3`

Comment: Sorry I updated the image for Table1. I tried pasting data from Excel but it was not getting pasted as table.

Comment: Any reason why you're using `'Yes'` and `'No'` instead of booleans?

Comment: 'yes' or 'No' I get it from files which I read.

Comment: I’m guessing you don’t have control over those files? At least you can modify the values in the DataFrame. Also, can you explain your most recent question on the answer by rhedak, about the whole splitting before iterating thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're in for an iterrows operation

It works like this

1. Iterate over the rows of the first DataFrame
2. Query the second DataFrame with an .isin operation for col1 (and regular == for col2)
3. Add the resulting entry to a pandas Series
4. Assign the pandas Series to your first DataFrame

I don't see any other way to do it without first cleaning the Data. I made a sample with makeshift data.
I suggest you save your data as csv files and upload it on pastebin or somewhere next time

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A,B','C','D'],'col2':[1,2,3],'col3':['Yes','Yes','No']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','B','C','D'],'col2':[1,1,2,3],'col4':['Bla','Foo','Sup','Asdf']})

_col4 = pd.Series()

for _row in df1.itertuples():

    if _row.col3=='Yes':
        _col4.loc[_row.Index] = ', '.join(
            df2[(df2['col1'].isin(_row.col1.split(',')))
                &(df2['col2']==_row.col2)]['col4'].tolist()
        )

df1['col4'] = _col4
```

Which gives

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   A,B 1   Yes Bla, Foo
1   C   2   Yes Sup
2   D   3   No  NaN
```

--
Edited based on comments below

Comment: Don’t use `iterrows`, it has some big disadvantages. `itertuples` is similar, and doesn’t have the same downsides.

Comment: For example, the docs clearly state that you should never modify something that you are iterating over, which you’re doing here. `itertuples` is a similar method which doesn’t have the same downsides. In any case, explicit loops should be a last resort when working with Pandas. Not only is `df1[‘col4’].loc[_index]` poor style, I believe it may be a form of chained indexing, which is really bad. In fact, the right side of that expression also seems to be a case of chained indexing. Finally, I believe that `.tolist()` is unnecessary, I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect your comments. I did some research and it seems itertuples is a lot faster. I don't really see any other downsides to iterrows and I like to use it when I have a column name that is a variable since it allows for dict like attr grabbing.

Also could you elaborate why it's better to assign the values to a pandas series and then to the DataFrame rather than just make the new Pandas Series a column of the DataFrame to begin with

Comment: Aside from the massive performance gap, `iterrows` returns a Series which means, to quote the docs _it does **not** preserve dtypes across the rows_.

Comment: I never thought about it this way but you're right it makes sense. If you have a mix of string and float values I guess it would return a Series with dtype object.
Thanks

Comment: Also, do you mind if I borrow the example data you created? I’m curious, want to give it a shot myself.

Comment: Sure go ahead. It's just dummy values

Comment: Hi Both, Thank you for all your help.  Quick question... what if we split the data where rows have only one record in 'col1' and rows with multiple records in 'Col1' and iterate on 2nd split table with rows which have multiple records? then merge final result tables. Will that make the process more fast?

Comment: I would say there is no easy answer on that one. It depends on the size of your DataFrame. For a few hundred rows/thousand itertuples is sufficiently fast that you won't notice a difference (might even be faster since splitting and merging also takes time). Somewhere beyond that scaling effects are going to make vector operations faster but you should really ask yourself if the speed gains validate the added complexity.

PS: if my answer solved your problem it would be much appreciated if you could accept it